# convert string to braille

Tags: javascript, typescript, discord.js

I'm working on a discord command that converts text to braille. I've found a few web-based examples of converting to other things such as morse code and tried to modify them but nothing seems to work.

The basic idea is that it would take in a string convert each character in the string to its braille equivalent and send that as an output.

Any help would be wonderful thanks <3

Comment: You can use a map of characters to their braille equivalents

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1 line in JavaScript.

```
string.toUpperCase().split("").map(c => "⠀⠁⠂⠃⠄⠅⠆⠇⠈⠉⠊⠋⠌⠍⠎⠏⠐⠑⠒⠓⠔⠕⠖⠗⠘⠙⠚⠛⠜⠝⠞⠟⠠⠡⠢⠣⠤⠥⠦⠧⠨⠩⠪⠫⠬⠭⠮⠯⠰⠱⠲⠳⠴⠵⠶⠷⠸⠹⠺⠻⠼⠽⠾⠿"[" A1B'K2L@CIF/MSP\"E3H9O6R^DJG>NTQ,*5<-U8V.%[$+X!&;:4\\0Z7(_?W]#Y)=".indexOf(c)]).join("");
```

One liners are cool, but here is a slightly better variation of the same code.

```
let map = " A1B'K2L@CIF/MSP\"E3H9O6R^DJG>NTQ,*5<-U8V.%[$+X!&;:4\\0Z7(_?W]#Y)=".split("").reduce((o, n, i) => {
  return o[n] = "⠀⠁⠂⠃⠄⠅⠆⠇⠈⠉⠊⠋⠌⠍⠎⠏⠐⠑⠒⠓⠔⠕⠖⠗⠘⠙⠚⠛⠜⠝⠞⠟⠠⠡⠢⠣⠤⠥⠦⠧⠨⠩⠪⠫⠬⠭⠮⠯⠰⠱⠲⠳⠴⠵⠶⠷⠸⠹⠺⠻⠼⠽⠾⠿"[i],
    o[n.toLowerCase()] = o[n], o;
}, {});

function toBraile(string) {
    return string.split("").map(c => map[c]).join("");
}

console.log(toBraile("test="));
```

Perhaps the conversion of `split("")` and `join("")` can also be improved, I'd be happy if someone has something to say on that.

Braille strings snatched from [the braile ascii wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Braille_ASCII).

Comment: Did you find this somewhere or did you just make it up on the spot?

Comment: @ShamPooSham I stole the strings from wikipedia, the rest is pretty simple.

Comment: I'm actually really impressed by how flawlessly this works. ill have to look into maps more, thank you very much for the answer. @php_nub_qq

Comment: @phantom I added another version of the same code that you'd probably want to use instead of the original answer.

Comment: I think you should link to the page you got this from

Comment: @MrMythical now that you mentioned it, I had a difficult time finding it again lol

Comment: @php_nub_qq very good solution works flawlessly again. the only issue I'm having is with typescript throwing type errors every 30 seconds but that's no fault of the code. tyvm for your continued help with this.

Comment: Thanks for the easy one-liner: "There are 10 types of people in the world, those who understand binary and those who don't." --> "There are 2 types of people in the world, those who can draw conclusions from incomplete facts."